# Enable whatsApp send button with "pure" javascript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

How could I insert a text in the WhatsApp message div and activate the send button with pure javascript? This is for an extension to the chrome, not for an illicit attitude.

I can with textContent in div, but the send button does not appear.

That is the code:

```
suggestion.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const inputText = document.querySelector('div._2FVVk._2UL8j')
    inputText.classList.add('focused')
    const textBox = document.querySelector('#main > footer > div._3ee1T._1LkpH.copyable-area > div._3uMse > div > div._3FRCZ.copyable-text.selectable-text')
    textBox.textContent = event.target.textContent
    document.querySelector('span[data-icon="send"]').click()
})
```

Note: I tried with ".focus()", but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this?

```
var inputMessageBox = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable='true']")[1]; 
var message = "Test Message";
var uiEvent = document.createEvent("UIEvents"); 
inputMessageBox.innerHTML = message; 
uiEvent.initUIEvent("input", true, true, window, 1); 
inputMessageBox.dispatchEvent(uiEvent); 

var mouseEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
mouseEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
document.querySelector('span[data-icon="send"]').dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
```